# My app showing black status bar in ios 7 but I want default white iOS 7 style

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I have upgraded the app from XCode 4.5 to XCode 5. The base sdk is iOS 7 and deployment target is 5.0. The problem is that the status bar is black but I want default white style of iOS 7. Please see the attached snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your plist file set NO the `View controller-based status bar appearance` property

2) At your `appDelegate` add this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 20)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: i would have seen this starting of the day because my total day wasted for this thank you boss +1

Answer (score 3):

In Info.plist Add Row:

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance, set value NO
```

Than in AppDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, add those rows:

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 0):

In app delegate set StatusBarStyle

> [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have UIStatusBarStyleDefault set

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html

Answer (score 0):

[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

Also add UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance in .plist to YES